# Improving security with JS

Tags: javascript

I’m trying some little ideas, and I’ve hit a snag.

At the moment, when a user logs in, their password is stored in a variable which is handled later. Obviously all one has to do to get hold of the password is to go into the developer tools or console or whatever and add a statement like `alert(pass.value);`.

I know this is unrealistic but its been bugging me. Is there any way of detecting an alert statement and scrambling the password somehow? A regex or string replace?

Thanks!

Comment: No javascript is completely insecure, as it gets executed on the client. Means, the client could even remove the code which prevents alert statements and so on.

You should move all your security things to server site - wherefore do you need to have the password in a javascript variable?

Comment: Trust me this is VERY realistic!  This is a dangerous approach, and the best solution is to not store this information in the client but to create a single use token upon successful authentication.

Comment: You should probably rethink your approach of storing the password client side. If you must you could store a MD5 hash.

Comment: MD5 is broken. Use sha1

Comment: MD5 is broken for verification of documents but it is still a viable approach to obscuring a password. Still none of this should be done client side so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have a secure system, don't store the password on the client side. There is absolutely nothing you can do in JavaScript that will prevent somebody from accessing the password if it is stored in a JavaScript variable.

All of your authentication should be handled on the server side. If you are storing passwords somewhere, do not store them in plain text, and do not use a home-brew encryption method. Cryptology is full of minefields and it's very easy to get something wrong, and I would recommend using a well thought-out system like [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against keeping any kind of credential information client-side. One viable solution that's easy to implement is is a security token password. A simple process would look like this:

- User access website. Informs credentials.
- Website validates credentials. Creates temporary token associated with user ID, stores it client-side.
- User access website. Informs token.
- Token is validated against storage, user identified.